# WPF Report as EmbeddedResource Crashing

Tags: c#, wpf, report

I'm having a lot of trouble with getting `Reporting` working in `WPF`. This is the error I get;

[image]

This is the path I am using;

`WpfReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "MyProject.View.Admin.PhoneRecords.Reports.PhoneNumbersReport.rdlc";`

No matter what I seem to try, whether I use `ReportEmbeddedResource` or `ReportPath`, it just does not seem to work.

I can't see any reason why it isn't a legal path either, and I am unsure about the `IntermediateFormatVersion`.